# invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-opengraph

When I paste the URL of my website in Facebook debugger, its not picking the title and also the image. In view source of my page, the `og:title` and also `og:image` are getting rendered but facebook **scraper** is not reading any. The error says:

```
Object at URL 
'https://www.qantas.com.au/fflyer/do/dyns/joinffp?code=FAMILYFREE' of type 
'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
```

Comment: Click on the “See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL” link at the bottom of the debug tool output. And then go and do some debugging, to find out why it only gets to see that.

Comment: Thanks for you response.  The scraper is not reading any of the meta tags(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.qantas.com.au%2Ffflyer%2Fdo%2Fdyns%2Fjoinffp%3Fcode%3DFAMILYFREE). Even though my page has the required meta tags. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: _Your server_ seems to be delivering different content, based on whether a normal browser, or the FB scraper requests your page. So you need to go and find out why.

Comment: Finally found problem from unnecessary spacing on property like

`<meta property="og:title " content="Hello World!">`

Comment: Related: [Why can't Open Graph checkers detect Open Graph data?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/124673/52079)

Answer (score 3):

Change your link from https to http
I had the same problem.